# Is it possible to make migrations from db not from model?

Tags: django, database, django-models

Suppose, we have a db's backup and a django program. The program do not have any migrations. First we restore db, that has created table and data. Now we want to make migrations from available db. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Django has the `inspectdb` method, which is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb).

But if the Django app already has the models defined that correspond to the backed up database, then you can just run `makemigrations` (follow @Shafikur's instructions).

Comment: you know, I have a backup from my db on VPS. Then I had some changes on my local project. for example I changes some models. Now I want to upload my project on VPS, but I have some conflict between migrations files on local project with VPS project. I thought, I should recreate my db and restore backup, then recreate migrations from db and finally make migration last changes of project. Is it possibel or not

Comment: In that case it's better if you resolve the conflicts locally first: go back to a point that is identical to your VPS db. Delete all the migrations that were created after that and re-create the migrations to reach the VPS state (follow @shafikur's instructions). Then change your models and create new migrations. So that on production you can just migrate normally. You must make sure that you have migrations that lead you to the exact same tables as you have on VPS first, you can't start from your modified local models.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your corresponding database terminals and delete all the records from you django_migrations table with

```
delete from django_migrations;
```

Go to terminal and run remove all files in migrations folder with

```
rm -rf <app>/migrations/
```

Reset all the migrations of the Django's built-in apps like admin with the command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Create initial migrations for each and every app:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app>
```

To create initial fake migrations just run

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```